# Manage data for multiple ads accounts by Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

my team uses many Facebook Business Manager to manage multiple Ad Accounts. Usually our employees will check the Amount Spent and Bill manually in Facebook sites. But now the number of ad accounts increases, I would like to automate the tasks: syncing data from Facebook to our own database (for high manager to view).

I tried with my own Facebook Account (by my own facebook App), I can get the Amount Spent already. My questions are:

- What is the API to get Amount Billed, I searched around but not yet found
- Because the number of ad accounts is big, what will be the good approach? (I am thinking of create a sole app and let the advertisers authorize it, And use the token to call Graph API; 2nd way is: each facebook user create their own app, this will not need Facebook to approve the app).

Sorry for my bad English, I am really new to Facebook API, please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Budget,Spend... with Ad Set (`lifetime_budget,daily_budget`)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign#fields

and get report Cpc,cpm... with Insight

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/#fields

Comment: Thanks bro, I could get those data from Marketing API of Facebook. But my question was about "Billing" data. Not "Spent Amount" (which was in Marketing API).